# Asking a closed question again with improved wording from another OP

Tags: discussion

So we have this question:
[How does comma operator work in this program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610839/how-does-comma-operator-work-in-this-program)

In the comment someone wrote that he has rewritten the question and dropped a link to this newer question:
[How Comma-separated expressions as condition in a for-loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611230/how-comma-separated-expressions-as-condition-in-a-for-loop-work)

Is this legitmate, I kinda feel like this is wrong. He should improve the original question instead. This feels like a rep-grab....

Comment: It's not clear to me what "This feels like a rep-grab" is meant to imply. Surely we should be judging questions, not intentions?

Comment: @KamiKaze Sorry for the confusing, I´ve felt it would be better if I would make my own question instead of to *completely* deform the original question and the question seemed to be closed soon. BTW: Moderators may merge the both if they want to. I got no problem with that.

Comment: @jpp this is my explanation for the "wrong feeling" and why I started this, you are welcome to disagree as I was just stating my feelings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people are posting nearly identical questions all day long. Just most of them aren't telling us whether it's "inspired by" something else or came up organically. Are we going to apply the same thinking there too?

**Judge the question on its own merits, don't worry about how the OP got to asking it.**

Answer (score 3):

The original question is unclear, only the asker of that question can clarify it to make it answerable. It also needs editing to convert the screenshot into text.

Perhaps the other question is what the asker meant, perhaps it isn't. It's better not to guess at that. So asking a new question, assuming its not a duplicate of some other already asked question here, seems entirely legitimate.

You don't usually get much rep from questions, it's mainly answers that generate rep because people vote more on answers so, let's just assume good intentions here i.e. that this question and its answer may help someone here someday which is a good thing.

Comment: Shall I delete my question? But SO says not to delete questions which already have answers. Can the moderators merge it anyway?

Comment: I agree that generally the new question was better (but still with some room for improvement in the formatting at least when I saw it). I am asking for the policy not to start a witchhunt. I am glad that @RobertS-ReinstateMonica is participating. I just had a bad feeling about this and wanted to get community input.

Comment: @KamiKaze For me, It is no problem to delete my one. Only Problem: The answers and comments to them would be thrown away and SO forces to keep questions which have already answers alive. Something like a merge with the answers from my question to the other question would be appreciated.

Comment: The other question is unclear and not text, your question isn't. Yours should stay, the other (unless improved by the OP) should be deleted.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica also, your question *might be different* from the original one. I really don't know - there is not enough detail there to know *which* commas the original asker meant. You were focused on the ones inside the `for` declaration, but perhaps the original author meant `int i,j`. In which case, it's two different questions. Perhaps the original author meant both `int i,j` and the `for`, in which case, the two questions partially overlap but are still different. But most importantly, your question makes sense, the original really doesn't need to be kept around.